# Wouldn't it make more sense for reputation to be universal to all StackExchange communities?

Tags: feature-request

I was surprised to find that my newly earned reputation points in this community don't seem to carry over to other communities. And I just don't see the point in this. It's kind of like having to go for a new driving examination every time you arrive at a new city. You shouldn't have to prove yourself repeatedly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reputation does carry over in a certain way: reaching 200 points on one site gets you +100 on every site. (This is why I have 101 here, for example.) Reaching the level of 200 is earning a universal driver's license. With 100 points one is exempt from new user restrictions, (such as a limit on the number of links in a post) and is able to  comment anywhere and participate on meta.

Beyond that, reputation crosses into *moderation* abilities: editing posts by other users, closing their questions, deleting their questions and answers. It would not make sense to grant such privileges on a programming site on the basis of user's contributions to a cooking site, or the other way around.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to the other answer, reputation is supposed to show how much of an expert you are on the topic of the site - which is why you get past the new user restrictions on other sites, but not all reputation.